# R Go to next iteration (which is two for loops before the current one) in loop using next

Tags: r, optimization, job-scheduling

I am working on optimizing job orders, with a precedence matrix. 
For example; job 8 cannot be performed before job 6 is finished. If this is the case, my precedence matrix on position [8,6] shows a one. If there is no precedence relation, for example for position [1,2], then it shows a zero.

In my current code I use the 'next' command to go to the next iteration if the precedence matrix shows a 1. However, the way it is programmed right now it just goes to the next j, while I want it to go to the next 'i' (next job to consider). However, the i is one loop before the if loop where 'next' is used. Is there a way to make it go to the for(i in n:jobs) loop instead of the next for(j in n:jobs)?

Below my current code

```
# Initialisatie
nJobs = 10
jobDone = rep(FALSE, nJobs) 

currentJob = 1;
jobDone[currentJob] = TRUE;
totalFine = 0; 
finishingTime = durations[currentProject]

jobOrder = c(currentJob);
jobFines = c(totalFine);
jobIndFines = c(totalFine)
jobTimes = c(finishingTime)
jobIndTimes = c(durations[currentJob])

for(iter in 1:(nJobs-1))
{
  bestFine = -1;
  bestOrder = -1;

    for(i in 1:nJobs)
    {
      for(j in 1:nJobs){
      if(precedences[i,j] == 1){ next } #hoe kom ik nu naar de volgende i ipv de volgende j?
        else{

    if( ! jobDone[i]  )
    {
      # If this is the first option or the cheapest option, we update the best option
      if(bestOrder == -1 || ((finishingTime+durations[i])-deadlines[i])*fines[i] > bestFine) 
      {
        bestFine = ((finishingTime+durations[i])-deadlines[i])*fines[i];
        bestOrder = i;
      }
        }
      }


    }
  }
  # Add the best job to the order of jobs
  jobDone[bestOrder] = TRUE;
  jobOrder[iter+1] = bestOrder;
  # Update the current order of projects
  fine = ((finishingTime+durations[bestOrder])-deadlines[bestOrder])*fines[bestOrder]
  jobIndFines[iter+1] = fine
  if (fine>0){
    totalFine = totalFine + fine;
  }
  jobFines[iter+1] = totalFine;
  #jobIndFines[iter+1] = totalFine - jobFines[iter];
  finishingTime = finishingTime + durations[bestOrder];
  jobTimes[iter+1] = finishingTime
  jobIndTimes[iter+1] = durations[bestOrder]
}
totalFine
finishingTime
jobOrder
jobFines
jobTimes
jobIndTimes
jobDone
jobIndFines
```

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Try `break`.

These code snippets illustrate the difference between `next` and `break`.

`next` restarts the *current* loop at its *next* index value:

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  for (j in 1:2) {
    print(paste("j =", j))
    next
    print("Python is better than R at everything.") # Never prints, obviously.
  }
  print(paste("i =", i))
}
#> [1] "j = 1"
#> [1] "j = 2"
#> [1] "i = 1"
#> [1] "j = 1"
#> [1] "j = 2"
#> [1] "i = 2"
```

`break` gets you out of the current loop entirely and passes control to the next statement outside the loop:

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  for (j in 1:2) {
    print(paste("j =", j))
    break
    print("Python is better than R at everything.") # Never prints, obviously.
  }
  print(paste("i =", i))
}
#> [1] "j = 1"
#> [1] "i = 1"
#> [1] "j = 1"
#> [1] "i = 2"
```